# Table has incorrect timestamps that need to be converted

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

we have a table where every timestamp for some reason has the hours as "12" and the minutes is actually the hours and the seconds is actually the minutes.

Example: `13-JAN-24 12.10.02.000000000 AM` is actually `13-JAN-24 10.02.00.000000000 AM` or `13-JAN-24 10:02 AM`

How can i convert all of these times so that i either ignore the hours all together or extract the minutes and seconds from the original timestamp and convert ot to the correct timestamp?

Comment: Why are these stored as string values in the first place? The database _will not provide good or simple tools to correct this,_ and that is because the database _expects you to use the correct data type_.  Instead, you'll be stuck doing some fairly ugly string evaluation and manipulation.

Comment: When i check the DB it says its stored as TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Correcting the data is easy, but if you haven't identified why the data is being inserting in the incorrect format and fixed that, you'll end up with new rows being wrong, and it'll be harder to work out which rows are wrong next time you want to fix the data. Have you found the root cause of the incorrect data?

Comment: "12.10.02.000000000 AM" is `00:10:02.0' - so the hours component is actually zero, not 12. Apart from that, how do you know the values are wrong?

Comment: {back from lunch} If it's `timestamp(6)`, that's actually a binary format that isn't human readable; the value you see printed is a convenience of your tooling, and _if what it shows you is accurate_, its worse even than the data is not inserted correctly, but rather that it's setting a completely wrong value.

Comment: @Boneist The root cause is never gonna be fixed honestly, companies too big to ever change it, trust me, its just not important enough to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET timestamp_column = CAST(TRUNC(timestamp_column, 'DD') AS TIMESTAMP)
                     + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp_column) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
                     + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM timestamp_column) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (timestamp_column) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-13 00:10:02.000000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:23:59.000000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-02 00:00:00.000000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `UPDATE` the table contains:

| TIMESTAMP_COLUMN |
| --- |
| 2024-01-13 10:02:00.000000000 |
| 2024-01-01 23:59:00.000000000 |
| 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tvXd6Dx3)

Answer (score 1):

As Boneist says in the comments: Fixing the wrong times is easy. After all, you just have to separate the date from the time part first, then add back the time part reduced by twelve hourse and multiplied by 60.

```
update mytable
set ts = cast(trunc(ts) as timestamp) + (ts - trunc(ts) - interval '12' hour) * 60;

commit;
```

Only, if you update your data and then the same faulty process writes more timestamps into the table, how to tell the corrected ones from the new faulty ones? So find the culprit first, eliminate it, and only then update your data.

Comment: That would give you 2023-12-14 10:02, not 2024-01-13 10:02 - the calculation ends up as 60 * just under 12 hours -> just under 30 days. But that's because the sample time is 12 *AM* so midnight, not - as the OP seemed to interpret it - midday, so you don't need to handle that at all. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I1viBdJa) for fun. I'm not convinced they actually have bad data...